# How to know why server keeps restarting?

Tags: linux, uptime

It seems that my server keeps restarting. I want to know why.

How can I know when the last time server was rebooted and why?

```
root     pts/0        139.193.156.125  Thu Aug  8 21:10   still logged in
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-358.11.1. Thu Aug  8 20:38 - 21:11  (00:33)
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-358.11.1. Thu Aug  8 20:15 - 21:11  (00:56)
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-358.11.1. Thu Aug  8 19:16 - 21:11  (01:55)
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-358.11.1. Thu Aug  8 18:56 - 21:11  (02:14)
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-358.11.1. Thu Aug  8 18:24 - 21:11  (02:47)
root     pts/1        139.193.156.125  Thu Aug  8 18:16 - crash  (00:07)
root     pts/0        195.254.135.181  Thu Aug  8 18:10 - crash  (00:13)
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-358.11.1. Thu Aug  8 17:52 - 21:11  (03:19)
root     pts/0        195.254.135.181  Thu Aug  8 17:38 - crash  (00:13)
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-358.11.1. Thu Aug  8 17:08 - 21:11  (04:02)
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-358.11.1. Thu Aug  8 16:58 - 21:11  (04:12)
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-358.11.1. Thu Aug  8 16:45 - 21:11  (04:26)
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-358.11.1. Thu Aug  8 16:35 - 21:11  (04:36)
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-358.11.1. Thu Aug  8 16:27 - 21:11  (04:44)
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-358.11.1. Thu Aug  8 15:59 - 21:11  (05:12)
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-358.11.1. Thu Aug  8 06:15 - 21:11  (14:56)
root     pts/1        208.74.121.102   Wed Aug  7 06:03 - 06:04  (00:00)
root     pts/1        208.74.121.102   Tue Aug  6 15:34 - 17:40  (02:05)
root     pts/0        139.193.156.125  Tue Aug  6 11:28 - 04:40 (1+17:11)
```

In Linux is there ANY WAY to know why the system rebooted? Specifically did high load cause it? If not that then What?

Comment: did you discover what caused it?

Comment: I have never seen a Linux server crashing so hard that it reboots itself. Your servers must have something really wrong. Otherwise, it's a power failure issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
/var/log/messages
```

That is the main log file you should check for messages related to this. Additionally either `/var/log/syslog` (Ubuntu) or `/var/log/secure` (CentOS)

To find out when your server was last rebooted just type `uptime` to see how long it has been up.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the following 2 commands (`who` & `last`) to find out the last time the system was rebooted and also messages about previous shutdown or runlevel changes.

#### Last time system booted?

For this you can use the `who` command. Specifically with the `-b` switch.

```
$ who -b
         system boot  2013-08-01 17:56
```

This says the last time the system was booted was 2013-08-01.

#### Past reboots

If you're interested in seeing a more extensive list of previous reboots you can use the `last` command.

```
$ last reboot | less
reboot   system boot  2.6.35.14-106.fc Thu Aug  1 17:56 - 02:03 (7+08:06)   
reboot   system boot  2.6.35.14-106.fc Thu Aug  1 09:41 - 17:55  (08:14)    
reboot   system boot  2.6.35.14-106.fc Thu Jul 25 15:24 - 17:55 (7+02:31)   
reboot   system boot  2.6.35.14-106.fc Thu Jul 18 18:05 - 15:23 (6+21:17)   
...
```

#### Past system shutdowns & runlevel changes?

You can use the `last` command for this too. You'll need to use the `-x` switch.

```
$ last -x | less
saml     pts/7        :pts/6:S.0       Sat Aug  3 21:30 - 21:30  (00:00)    
saml     pts/6        :0.0             Sat Aug  3 21:29 - 21:30  (00:01)    
saml     pts/4        :0.0             Fri Aug  2 21:49 - 22:16 (2+00:26)   
saml     pts/2        :0.0             Fri Aug  2 13:30 - 22:16 (2+08:45)   
saml     pts/1        :0.0             Fri Aug  2 13:05   still logged in   
saml     pts/0        :0.0             Fri Aug  2 12:37   still logged in   
saml     pts/0        :0.0             Fri Aug  2 12:35 - 12:37  (00:02)    
saml     pts/0        :0.0             Thu Aug  1 17:58 - 12:35  (18:36)    
saml     tty1         :0               Thu Aug  1 17:56   still logged in   
runlevel (to lvl 5)   2.6.35.14-106.fc Thu Aug  1 17:56 - 02:04 (7+08:08)   
reboot   system boot  2.6.35.14-106.fc Thu Aug  1 17:56 - 02:04 (7+08:08)   
shutdown system down  2.6.35.14-106.fc Thu Aug  1 17:55 - 17:56  (00:00)    
runlevel (to lvl 6)   2.6.35.14-106.fc Thu Aug  1 17:55 - 17:55  (00:00)    
saml     tty2                          Thu Aug  1 17:54 - down   (00:01)    
root     tty2                          Thu Aug  1 17:53 - 17:54  (00:00)    
...
```

#### References

- [who man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/who)
- [last man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/last)

Comment: I got tons of system boot. There is no clue of why the system is booting.

Answer (score 1):

To know when the last time server was rebooted you can use `tuptime`:

```
$ tuptime -t
No.        Startup Date                                          Uptime       Shutdown Date   End                                       Downtime

1     10:33:14 01/05/18     45 days, 0 hours, 39 minutes and 55 seconds   11:13:09 02/19/18   BAD   27 days, 21 hours, 51 minutes and 36 seconds
2     09:04:45 03/19/18      37 days, 7 hours, 6 minutes and 58 seconds   17:11:43 04/25/18   BAD   67 days, 18 hours, 36 minutes and 15 seconds
3     11:47:58 07/02/18                        6 minutes and 57 seconds   11:54:55 07/02/18   OK                                      27 seconds
4     11:55:22 07/02/18                         1 minute and 28 seconds   11:56:50 07/02/18   BAD                       2 minutes and 43 seconds
5     11:59:33 07/02/18                         1 minute and 38 seconds   12:01:11 07/02/18   OK                                      26 seconds
6     12:01:37 07/02/18                        6 minutes and 52 seconds   12:08:29 07/02/18   OK                                      26 seconds
7     12:08:55 07/02/18                                      14 seconds   12:09:09 07/02/18   BAD                       8 minutes and 40 seconds
8     12:17:49 07/02/18                        5 minutes and 41 seconds   12:23:30 07/02/18   OK                                      27 seconds
9     12:23:57 07/02/18   111 days, 19 hours, 56 minutes and 41 seconds
```

And to know why, the command `journalctl` and the files under the directory `/var/log/` are those that you need to look at.

Comment: On server-grade systems, there can also be a hardware error log, viewable either by `ipmitool` or by a vendor-specific utility. Such a log could indicate if the system is shutting down because of overheating, loss of power, failure of too many cooling fans at the same time, failure of error-correcting RAM module, or some other hardware fault.