# Shutdown log Linux UserName

Tags: shutdown

Can I know who issued the `shutdown` command on any *nix system in a multi-user system? I want to know the name of the user who issued the particular command.

Comment: EDIT : I Guess it isn't the user who runs shutdown but some system process. So in that case, how to know from the system process, who initiated the `shutdown`. Look here : http://pastebin.com/5g6RpmuM

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**NOTE:** This answer primary focuses on showing when a system was booted/shutdown. Getting the actual user that performed the shutdown is a bit trickier. The best way I've seen it done, is to limit access to a system, and only give certain operators `sudo` rights to the `shutdown` command. This will give you a log of who ran what `sudo` command and at what time they did it. This is far superior then to attempt to hack the `shutdown` command!

#### 1. Parsing log files

Most systems already have this info contained in their logs, you just have to know what to look for.

The log files `/var/log/messages`, `/var/log/syslog` (Ubuntu) or `/var/log/secure` (CentOS) will typically have this.

***Examples***

```
$ sudo grep -iE "shutdown|boot" secure*
secure-20131215:Dec 14 02:08:56 greeneggs sudo:     saml : TTY=pts/6 ; PWD=/home/saml ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/sbin/reboot
```

#### 2. Last time system booted?

For this you can use the `who` command. Specifically with the `-b` switch.

```
$ who -b
         system boot  2013-08-01 17:56
```

This says the last time the system was booted was 2013-08-01.

#### 3. Past reboots

If you're interested in seeing a more extensive list of previous reboots you can use the `last` command.

```
$ last reboot | less
reboot   system boot  2.6.35.14-106.fc Thu Aug  1 17:56 - 02:03 (7+08:06)   
reboot   system boot  2.6.35.14-106.fc Thu Aug  1 09:41 - 17:55  (08:14)    
reboot   system boot  2.6.35.14-106.fc Thu Jul 25 15:24 - 17:55 (7+02:31)   
reboot   system boot  2.6.35.14-106.fc Thu Jul 18 18:05 - 15:23 (6+21:17)   
...
```

#### 4. Past system shutdowns & runlevel changes?

You can use the `last` command for this too. You'll need to use the `-x` switch.

```
$ last -x | less
saml     pts/7        :pts/6:S.0       Sat Aug  3 21:30 - 21:30  (00:00)    
saml     pts/6        :0.0             Sat Aug  3 21:29 - 21:30  (00:01)    
saml     pts/4        :0.0             Fri Aug  2 21:49 - 22:16 (2+00:26)   
saml     pts/2        :0.0             Fri Aug  2 13:30 - 22:16 (2+08:45)   
saml     pts/1        :0.0             Fri Aug  2 13:05   still logged in   
saml     pts/0        :0.0             Fri Aug  2 12:37   still logged in   
saml     pts/0        :0.0             Fri Aug  2 12:35 - 12:37  (00:02)    
saml     pts/0        :0.0             Thu Aug  1 17:58 - 12:35  (18:36)    
saml     tty1         :0               Thu Aug  1 17:56   still logged in   
runlevel (to lvl 5)   2.6.35.14-106.fc Thu Aug  1 17:56 - 02:04 (7+08:08)   
reboot   system boot  2.6.35.14-106.fc Thu Aug  1 17:56 - 02:04 (7+08:08)   
shutdown system down  2.6.35.14-106.fc Thu Aug  1 17:55 - 17:56  (00:00)    
runlevel (to lvl 6)   2.6.35.14-106.fc Thu Aug  1 17:55 - 17:55  (00:00)    
saml     tty2                          Thu Aug  1 17:54 - down   (00:01)    
root     tty2                          Thu Aug  1 17:53 - 17:54  (00:00)    
...
```

#### References

- [who man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/who)
- [last man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/last)
- [How to know why server keeps restarting?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86061/how-to-know-why-server-keeps-restarting/86079#86079)

Comment: Note that, as far as I can tell, this still doesn't tell you *who* shut it down, since it will likely be root. +1 however, because the other answer is dangerous, and this is about as good as it gets without dbus.

Comment: @ChrisDown - yes this is actually bits from another answer I gave a couple months back. I was tempted to mark this Q as a dup, but he's asking for who, and that isn't actually feasible, as you've indicated as well. The other Q was asking for when and who.

Comment: @ChrisDown - I added a blub at the top mentioning the difficulties in getting the user, and the use of `sudo` was the most appropriate. Feel free to word smith it further if you feel it needs additional verbiage.

Comment: @ASCIIbetical - is there something wrong with this solution?

Comment: @slm while I do appreciate all your efforts and research that you did for the solution, it doesn't explicitly answer my `who` aspect. You say filter out from system file, but which one? I checked auth.log, there is no log for who started the shutdown. Which log file should you tell I look at ?

Comment: @ASCIIbetical - fair enough, never accept an answer unless you feel it solves your problem. 8-). Are you using `sudo` on your system? I believe in my A I explained that using `sudo` will be the only way you'll find username's and shutdown events. In the example I showed, the log file `/var/log/secure*` contains these records of userX running `reboot` or `shutdown` commands.

Comment: @ASCIIbetical - also there is no general solution, I for example am using Fedora/CentOS/RHEL which use the file `/var/log/secure*`, other distros opt for different logs altogether, so you'll have to be more specific in your Q if you really want the "who" information.

Comment: Regarding Ubuntu, alas, hoping to `/var/log/syslog` didn't help.

Comment: @slm Kindly have a look here: I initiated a shutdown at 10:10:34 and started computer at 10:11:16, alas, no username is present: Log of `/var/log/syslog`  `Jan  3 10:10:34 thinktank rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.6" x-pid="508" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
Jan  3 10:11:16 thinktank kernel: imklog 5.8.6, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
Jan  3 10:11:16 thinktank rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.6" x-pid="711" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start`

Comment: I Guess it isn't the user who runs shutdown but some system process. So in that case, how to know from the system process, who initiated the shutdown. I Guess it isn't the user who runs shutdown but some system process. So in that case, how to know from the system process, who initiated the shutdown. Look here :http://pastebin.com/5g6RpmuM

Comment: I initiated a shutdown at 10:10:34 and started my system at 10:11:16, no username is there.

Comment: @ASCIIbetical - this was my exact point in the 1st paragraph. You can't know because there is a interface that catches the signal to shutdown/reboot and then triggers it. This process runs as root so you'll never see a username that way. Using sudo and walling off access to shutdown/reboot is just how sysadmins do this. We managed a fortune 500 companies infrastructure and this is how we did it there.

Comment: Oh, Thanks then. I guess, that's how its gonna be done. Thanks for the inputs. Always a pleasure to learn from `pros` like you. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @ASCIIbetical - the pleasure is mine. I like helping others make sense of all the noise 8-)